# "Site Wide" cookie only actually ends up applying to certain pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

In the latest incarnation of my website, I've got a dark/light mode switch I've built into my new Wordpress theme. I've got no problems creating, reading and modifying the cookie, but the problem is, it only seems to end up applying to the pages I toggle the switch on, even though I specify "/" in the cookie creation.

Here's my PHP for initial cookie creation:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["darkmode"])){
$cookie_name = "darkmode";
$cookie_value = "0";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}

if ($_COOKIE["darkmode"]) {
    $extraBodyClass = "d4rkm0d3";
} else {
    $extraBodyClass = "";
}
```

And here's the JS for updating the cookie:

```
function darkModeSwitch() {
    if (jQuery("body").hasClass("d4rkm0d3")) {
        jQuery("body").removeClass("d4rkm0d3");
        document.cookie = "darkmode=0";
    } else {
        jQuery("body").addClass("d4rkm0d3");
        document.cookie = "darkmode=1";
    }
}
```

Just some additional notes: I'm doing this on my dev machine on localhost (LAMP stack - latest Ubuntu, Apache2, MySQL 8.0.18, PHP 7.4). Wordpress is 5.3.1 (not doing anything that'll break in .2 really). Theme is homebrew with Blankslate as a core. Only plugins on setup are CPT-UI, Advanced Custom Fields, Yoast, and WP Importer. No caching is set up, and I'm testing on the latest Chrome build with the inspector tool open constantly and cache disabled on reload.

Comment: So you're saying you load page A, turn on dark mode, navigate to page B, darkmode is off, the navigate to page A and it's on again...?

Comment: Have you verified on the non-working pages that the HTTP request does not include the cookie? You can do that with the browser "Network" developer tool.

Comment: Also how certain are you that the non-working pages include the PHP code to set the extra class on the `<body>` tag?

Comment: @ChrisG - exactly.

Comment: @Pointy - Yup, verified. The cookie code is in my header.php, and the JS is included on all pages via functions.php.

Comment: Right but have you looked at the HTTP requests?

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, no problems there it looks like.

Comment: @WFL OK if there are no problems with the HTTP request — meaning that the cookie **is** being sent — then the problem is somewhere in your PHP code.

Comment: Found it: you need `document.cookie = "darkmode=0;path=/";` or the JS code will set the cookie for the current path only. (The dev tools storage tab was showing multiple cookies, all with different paths)

Comment: @ChrisG that got it - thanks!